# How do I enable 4k resolution output?

Tags: graphics

I've recently bought a PC with MSI b85i motherboard and its supposed to support 4k resolution output. Ive done a fresh install of Ubuntu onto the new PC, plugged an HDMI cable into it and connected it to my 4k TV and I can only set resolution as high as 1080p. Any suggestions for how to actually use the 4k? at this stage I don't know if its an ubuntu problem or one somewhere else down the line.

Thanks!

Comment: Altough I have no answer for your problem by myself, you might want to take a look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164924

Answer (score 1):

From the specs:

> - 1 x DVI-I port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200 @60Hz, 24bpp
> - 1 x HDMI port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200 @60Hz, 24bpp
> - 1 x DisplayPort, supporting a maximum resolution of 4096x2160@24Hz, 24bpp/ 2560x1600@60Hz, 24bpp/ 1920x1080@60Hz, 36bpp

You need to use the DisplayPort port.

This is fairly common with 4K stuff, either for resolution or framerate. You *may also* run into driver issues down the line but for now, I would certainly look to the port for the first fix.